# Transfer Winform Data to web browser(Chrome, Mozila FireFox, Safari etc)

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, .net-2.0

I am trying transfer data from a Windows Form application to a web browser. I achieve this for IE (Internet Explorer), but now I am trying to transfer this data to all browsers such as Chrome, Mozilla Firefox,Safari.

For IE I am using MSHTML.dll but I don't know to to achieve it for any of the other browsers.

Here is the code I use for IE:

```
InternetExplorer TargetIE = null;
IHTMLDocument2 document = null;
//Check whether the IE is opened
foreach (InternetExplorer internetExplorer in new ShellWindows())
{
  if (internetExplorer.Document is HTMLDocument)
      {
        TargetIE = internetExplorer;
        break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath You Can handle such kind of stuff

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var page = wc.DownloadString(arguments);
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(page);
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input");
               if (nodes != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode data in nodes)
                    {
                       //Do whatever you want........
                     }
                 }
              }
```

also download HtmlAgilityPack dll from this link [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

not sure I really understood your confusion. I think maybe you can formate your data as HTML, which is recognized by all the browsers, not only by IE. so, in your program, you should pay attention to fill and organize data into html files, maybe including some javascript. then, you can browse your html in your app using WebBrowser control, and the html also could be accessed by other browsers.

Comment: my Client want to transfer data from windows form such as values from textBox,DropDown Radio Button to Firefox Browser (eg I want to create winform application that can transfer login name, password to Yahoo Login page, on any browser)

Comment: I guess you want to develop a app to help users to login? so you need to automatically fill the login info(username, passowrd) into any browsers?

Comment: Yes, Now You Got It what exactly I want.

Comment: Interesting, but how do you know which HTML tag is used to fill in user name or password? I think your project is very nice, I ever tried to develop a similar one, but it failed after I met some problems, by the way, hope you can get it.